# maven gwt archetype does not find index.html

Tags: maven, gwt

I created a gwt project with maven archetype as follows:

**mvn -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo -DarchetypeArtifactId=gwt-maven-plugin -DarchetypeVersion=2.7.0 -DgroupId=ru.scrumdev.sample -DartifactId=example -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:generate**

When ask me for a module name I type **Example**. All ok, when I try mvn gwt:run Jetty is started but a 404 page is showed in the browser with:

**HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /Example.html. Reason:
    Not Found**

Some ideas? Thanks in advance

Edit:
If I package and deploy the war all works.